# Does EF5 Auto rollback when a save failed

Tags: entity-framework-5

This is my first time using EF.

I would like to know if EF 5 will auto rollsback on error when saving. I created a test app and it seems like it does but I'm not sure if its a setting.

Here is my code

```
  public Test()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       //Gets Gets unit of work for a specific context
       var s=DAL.DALHelper.GetUnitOfWork();

       var categoryRepo=s.GetRepository<Category>();
       var onlyRecord = s.GetRepository<Category>().GetById(3);
       onlyRecord.CategoryDescription = "Test2222";

       Category catToAdd=new Category();
       catToAdd.CategoryDescription="Test3";
       catToAdd.CategoryName="Toys";
       //This will break due to a constraint
       categoryRepo.Add(catToAdd);
       s.Save();
  }
```

I have seen lots of code on the web that shows running code within a transaction, so I'm a little skeptical on the auto rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit transaction for a call to `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, so any operations performed during a single `DbContext.SaveChanges()` call that throws an exception will roll back.  If you call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` twice and the second call results in an exception, the changes from the first `SaveChanges()` call will not be rolled back